# enyo, How to do horizontal scrolling

Tags: enyo

I have made a simple enyo app to teat scrolling.
It scrolls vertically, but not horizontal.  Allso the documentation says you must set the scroll size.  The example code usses flex: 1 for the size, could somebody explain how this works.

code
enyo.kind({
  name: "MyApps.MainApp",
  kind: enyo.VFlexBox,
  components: [
       {kind: "PageHeader", content: "Scroll"},
       {name:"curValue", content:("Sample Text")},
      {kind: "Button", caption: "Action", onclick: "btnClickA"},

```
   {kind: "Scroller", flex: 1, onScrollStart: "btnClick", components: [
   { content:("Sample Text1")},
   { content:("Sample Text2")}
```

]}

],
  btnClick: function() {
    this.$.curValue.setContent("Start Scroll");  // handle the button click
  },

```
btnClickA: function() {
this.$.curValue.setContent("Button click");  // handle the button click
```

}
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'flex' value refers to the proportion of the parent FlexBox that the specified child takes up. You should read up on [FlexBoxes](http://developer.palm.com/blog/2011/07/css-3-flexible-box-model-and-enyo-flex-layout/) to get a little better idea.  In the absence of other controls flex: 1 indicates the control should take up all of the parent's space.  If two controls were in the FlexBox and both were flex: 1 then they would equally share the parent's space.  If one was flex: 2 then it would take up twice (2x1) the space as the flex: 1 control. In other words, the flex value sets the relative proportion of the parent (less any non-flexed controls) that a child takes up.

What I believe you are missing is that you must put something inside the scroller that's wider than the width of the scroller, otherwise... there's nothing to scroll!  Hope that helps.